# How to make middleware respond on every request

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm testing `middleware` in `express` and I ran into a problem.

On my second line I use `app.use` to call testOne and testTwo.  When I visit my root / in a browser both of these `middleware` functions run.  However if I visit a random static file for example image.png or about.htm they don't fire off.  How do I make them fire off no matter what file I request?  Thanks so much for any help!

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(testOne, testTwo);

function testOne(request, response, next) {
    console.log('testOne ran');
}

function testTwo(request, response, next) {
    console.log('testTwo ran');
}

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.htm'));
});
```

Comment: Just do `app.use(testOne, testTwo, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
`

Comment: @Prakashsharma - That won't fix it by itself.  Middleware has to call `next()` in order to continue routing to the next handler (as shown in my answer).

Comment: @jfriend00 I know. But as OP said "_When I visit my root / in a browser both of these middleware functions run_", I assumed that he is already calling `next()` but haven't mentioned that in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All middleware has to call `next()` in order to continue routing onto the next route handler.

```
app.use(testOne, testTwo);

function testOne(request, response, next) {
    console.log('testOne ran');
    next();
}

function testTwo(request, response, next) {
    console.log('testTwo ran');
    next();
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If you don't call `next()` the route just gets stalled and does nothing else (until it probably eventually times out).

---

Also, if you want these middleware to fire on all requests, then you need to put them first before other request handlers that might actually handle the request such as `express.static()`.